# ImportErrorの解決方法

Tags: python, python3

事前にclass定義したICA使うため、

from ica import ICA

を実行した所、

ImportError: cannot import name 'ICA' from 'ica'　（ファイル名....py名）

というエラーが出ました。
これの解決方法がわかりません。

Comment: `ica` パッケージには `ICA` という名前のクラスやアトリビュートはなく、`ica` というクラスがあります。もしかして `from ica import ica` の間違いではないでしょうか？

Comment: 「事前にclass定義したICA使うため、」というのは、[ica 0.5 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ica/) ではなく、こちらの記事 [独立成分分析による音源分離](https://aidemy.net/magazine/685/) では無いですか？ そして解決していませんが質問と同様のQ&A [pythonでインポートができない](https://teratail.com/questions/348935) があります。直前の質問 [playsoundを使って音声を再生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82738/26370) と同様に、他の人が問題を再現・調査・回答出来るために十分な情報を追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

「事前にclass定義したICA」というのが、こちらの記事 [独立成分分析による音源分離](https://aidemy.net/magazine/685/) の`ica.py`と同等なものだとして、以下のような対処が考えられます。

- 一番単純なのはimportする呼び出し元のスクリプトファイルと`ica.py`を同じフォルダに格納し、そのフォルダをカレントフォルダとして呼び出し元のスクリプトファイルを実行することです。
- 同程度に単純なのは、`ica.py`ファイルの存在するフォルダを環境変数`PYTHONPATH`に設定または追加することです。
- importする呼び出し元のスクリプトファイルと`ica.py`を同じフォルダに格納し、import時に以下のようにカレントフォルダを移動する方法もあります。

```
import os
curdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from ica import ICA
os.chdir(curdir)
```

- 同様にimportする前に`ica.py`ファイルの存在するフォルダをモジュールパス変数のsys.pathの先頭などに追加する方法もあります。

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = 'path/to/ica.py folder'
from ica import ICA
```

- また`ica.py`を単体ではなく以下のようにパッケージの形態を整えて、`ica`フォルダが存在するフォルダを上記のいずれかの方法で`ica.py`が存在するフォルダの代りに追加する方法もあります。

  - `ica`フォルダを作成する
  - 以下のいずれかの方法でパッケージとしての形態を整える

    - `ica`フォルダの中に`__init__.py`ファイルを作成し、`ica.py`ファイルの内容をそのまま記述しておく
    - `ica`フォルダの中に`ica.py`ファイルコピーし、追加で`__init__.py`ファイルを作成し以下の内容を記述しておく

```
from .ica import ICA
```

Comment: import os
curdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from ica import ICA
os.chdir(curdir)    カレントフォルダを移動する方法を試してみましたが、　NameError: name '__file__' is not defined　というエラーが起きます。"__file__"のように囲む解決策がありますがそれでよいのですか？

Comment: それはおそらく確認方法が間違っています。Pythonインタプリタの対話モード(`>>>`のプロンプトが表示されている状態)でスクリプトを入力するとその状態(`NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`)になるようです。`os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__")))`というのは結局カレントフォルダのパスを取得しているのと変わりません。[os.path.abspath関数](https://www.solima.net/python/archives/321), [os.path.abspath(path)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) `ほとんどのプラットフォームでは、これは関数 normpath() を次のように呼び出した時と等価です: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))。`