# 「スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去」によるノイズ除去について

Tags: python

[「スペクトラルノイズ除去による雑音除去」による音声再生](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83065)

上記質問のプログラムを実行すると以下のメッセージが表示され、音声は再生されるのですが、ノイズ除去が完了できません。
対処方法を教えていただきたいです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
FutureWarning: Pass hop_length=512, win_length=2048 as keyword args. From version 0.10 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
  return librosa.istft(y, hop_length, win_length)
```

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter1d

def envelope(y, rate, threshold):
    """
    Args:
        - y: 信号データ
        - rate: サンプリング周波数
        - threshold: 雑音判断するしきい値
    Returns:
        - mask: 振幅がしきい値以上か否か
        - y_mean: Sound Envelop
    """
    y_mean = maximum_filter1d(np.abs(y), mode="constant", size=rate//20)
    mask = [mean > threshold for mean in y_mean]
    return mask, y_mean

import librosa


n_fft=2048  # STFTカラム間の音声フレーム数
hop_length=512  # STFTカラム間の音声フレーム数
win_length=2048  # ウィンドウサイズ
n_std_thresh=1.5  # 信号とみなされるために、ノイズの平均値よりも大きい標準偏差（各周波数レベルでの平均値のdB）が何個あるかのしきい値

def _stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length):
    return librosa.stft(y=y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)

def _amp_to_db(x):
    return librosa.core.amplitude_to_db(x, ref=1.0, amin=1e-20, top_db=80.0)



sample_rate= 32000

# 音声ファイルの読み込み
#noise_clip = open(r"C:\Users\1818067\birdvoice.wav")

path=r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\elect\birdvoice.wav'
sig, _ = librosa.load(path, sr=sample_rate)

# ノイズデータ取得
mask, noise_clip = envelope(sig, sample_rate, threshold=0.03)




noise_stft = _stft(noise_clip, n_fft, hop_length, win_length)
noise_stft_db = _amp_to_db(np.abs(noise_stft))  # dBに変換する

mean_freq_noise = np.mean(noise_stft_db, axis=1)
std_freq_noise = np.std(noise_stft_db, axis=1)
noise_thresh = mean_freq_noise + std_freq_noise * n_std_thresh


import scipy


n_grad_freq = 2  # マスクで平滑化する周波数チャンネルの数
n_grad_time = 4  # マスクを使って滑らかにする時間チャンネル数
prop_decrease = 1.0  # ノイズをどの程度減らすか


#data = open(r'C:\Users\1818067\birdvoice.wav')
#audio_clip = envelope(data).envelop

sample_rate= 32000

# 音声ファイルの読み込み
#noise_clip = open(r"C:\Users\1818067\birdvoice.wav")

path=r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\elect\birdvoice.wav'
sig, _ = librosa.load(path, sr=sample_rate)

# ノイズデータ取得
audio_clip, rate = librosa.load('birdvoice.wav')


# 音源もSTFTで特徴量抽出する
sig_stft = _stft(audio_clip, n_fft, hop_length, win_length)
sig_stft_db = _amp_to_db(np.abs(sig_stft))

# 時間と頻度でマスクの平滑化フィルターを作成
smoothing_filter = np.outer(
        np.concatenate(
            [
                np.linspace(0, 1, n_grad_freq + 1, endpoint=False),
                np.linspace(1, 0, n_grad_freq + 2),
            ]
        )[1:-1],
        np.concatenate(
            [
                np.linspace(0, 1, n_grad_time + 1, endpoint=False),
                np.linspace(1, 0, n_grad_time + 2),
            ]
        )[1:-1],
    )
smoothing_filter = smoothing_filter / np.sum(smoothing_filter)

# 時間と周波数のしきい値の計算
db_thresh = np.repeat(
        np.reshape(noise_thresh, [1, len(mean_freq_noise)]),
        np.shape(sig_stft_db)[1],
        axis=0,
    ).T
sig_mask = sig_stft_db < db_thresh
sig_mask = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(sig_mask, smoothing_filter, mode="same")
sig_mask = sig_mask * prop_decrease

mask_gain_dB = np.min(_amp_to_db(np.abs(sig_stft)))

def _db_to_amp(x,):
    return librosa.core.db_to_amplitude(x, ref=1.0)

sig_stft_db_masked = (
        sig_stft_db * (1 - sig_mask)
        + np.ones(np.shape(mask_gain_dB)) * mask_gain_dB * sig_mask
)

def _istft(y, hop_length, win_length):
    return librosa.istft(hop_length, win_length)

sig_imag_masked = np.imag(sig_stft) * (1 - sig_mask)
sig_stft_amp = (_db_to_amp(sig_stft_db_masked) * np.sign(sig_stft)) + (1j * sig_imag_masked)

recovered_signal = _istft(sig_stft_amp, hop_length, win_length)

import soundfile as sf

sf.write('clearvoice.wav', recovered_signal, 22050, subtype='PCM_16')

from playsound import playsound

playsound('clearvoice.wav')
```

Comment: warning message に関して、positional argument ではなく keyword で指定しなさい、という意味です。つまり、`return librosa.istft(y, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)` に変更する様に求めています。

Answer (score 0):

結局は冗長な処理が残っていたのだと思われます。
以下のようにすればファイルを何回も読んだり変換したりする処理は不要です。
先頭に`########`でコメントを付けた部分が変更点です。

```
######## 音声処理関連の import は先頭にまとめて必要なもののみ残す
import numpy as np
import librosa
import scipy

######## 元の音声データファイルをそのまま読み込むだけで変換処理は不要
audio_clip, _ = librosa.load(r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\elect\birdvoice.wav')

n_fft=2048  # STFTカラム間の音声フレーム数
hop_length=512  # STFTカラム間の音声フレーム数
win_length=2048  # ウィンドウサイズ
n_std_thresh=1.5  # 信号とみなされるために、ノイズの平均値よりも大きい標準偏差（各周波数レベルでの平均値のdB）が何個あるかのしきい値

def _stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length):
    return librosa.stft(y=y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)

def _amp_to_db(x):
    return librosa.core.amplitude_to_db(x, ref=1.0, amin=1e-20, top_db=80.0)

######## 音声ファイルを変換する処理は不要なので削除して読み込む処理を先頭に移動

######## 下記行の noise_clip を audio_clip に変更
noise_stft = _stft(audio_clip, n_fft, hop_length, win_length)
noise_stft_db = _amp_to_db(np.abs(noise_stft))  # dBに変換する

mean_freq_noise = np.mean(noise_stft_db, axis=1)
std_freq_noise = np.std(noise_stft_db, axis=1)
noise_thresh = mean_freq_noise + std_freq_noise * n_std_thresh

n_grad_freq = 2  # マスクで平滑化する周波数チャンネルの数
n_grad_time = 4  # マスクを使って滑らかにする時間チャンネル数
prop_decrease = 1.0  # ノイズをどの程度減らすか

######## 音声ファイル/ノイズデータを読む処理は不要

# 音源もSTFTで特徴量抽出する
sig_stft = _stft(audio_clip, n_fft, hop_length, win_length)
sig_stft_db = _amp_to_db(np.abs(sig_stft))

# 時間と頻度でマスクの平滑化フィルターを作成
smoothing_filter = np.outer(
        np.concatenate(
            [
                np.linspace(0, 1, n_grad_freq + 1, endpoint=False),
                np.linspace(1, 0, n_grad_freq + 2),
            ]
        )[1:-1],
        np.concatenate(
            [
                np.linspace(0, 1, n_grad_time + 1, endpoint=False),
                np.linspace(1, 0, n_grad_time + 2),
            ]
        )[1:-1],
    )
smoothing_filter = smoothing_filter / np.sum(smoothing_filter)

# 時間と周波数のしきい値の計算
db_thresh = np.repeat(
        np.reshape(noise_thresh, [1, len(mean_freq_noise)]),
        np.shape(sig_stft_db)[1],
        axis=0,
    ).T
sig_mask = sig_stft_db < db_thresh
sig_mask = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(sig_mask, smoothing_filter, mode="same")
sig_mask = sig_mask * prop_decrease

mask_gain_dB = np.min(_amp_to_db(np.abs(sig_stft)))

def _db_to_amp(x,):
    return librosa.core.db_to_amplitude(x, ref=1.0)

sig_stft_db_masked = (
        sig_stft_db * (1 - sig_mask)
        + np.ones(np.shape(mask_gain_dB)) * mask_gain_dB * sig_mask
)

def _istft(y, hop_length, win_length):
    return librosa.istft(y, hop_length, win_length) ######## 質問時の転記ミス y, が不足していた

sig_imag_masked = np.imag(sig_stft) * (1 - sig_mask)
sig_stft_amp = (_db_to_amp(sig_stft_db_masked) * np.sign(sig_stft)) + (1j * sig_imag_masked)

recovered_signal = _istft(sig_stft_amp, hop_length, win_length)

import soundfile as sf

sf.write('clearvoice.wav', recovered_signal, 22050, subtype='PCM_16')

from playsound import playsound

playsound('clearvoice.wav')
```

それから、`FutureWarning:...`と表示された部分は警告であってエラーでは無いでしょう。
もしかしたら何かしらの影響があるのかもしれませんが、今のところ問題は無いようです。

---

**追記**

@metropolis さんのコメントに従って、以下のようにキーワード指定にしたら警告メッセージは出なくなりましたね。

```
def _istft(y, hop_length, win_length):
    return librosa.istft(y, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)
```

Comment: きちんと実行できました。ありがとうございます！